# Mux Auto Addressing Circuit

Tags: voltage, i2c, multiplexer, comparator, voltage-reference

I am trying to build a circuit that will allow multiple (up to 4) muxes on the same I2C line. I am trying to get their addresses to increment with each new board connected. (Lines A0 to A2).

Here is my current circuit:
[image: Where B2 - B4 is the reference voltage that changes with each new board]

Where B2 - B4 is the reference voltage that changes with each new board.
I then add 3 voltage comparators per board that can adjust the Pins A0-A2.
However the problem is that After the board that contains the R4 resistor, the ground is not connected (as all boards are similiar). This would need human intervention (connecting jumper to ground).

I would like to know if someone has done something similiar or is there an easier/more elegant solution to this process.

Comment: Have you tried this : TCA9548A I2C : 64 sensors I2C for 8 addresses ... https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/downloads

Comment: Can you use the Maxim (orig. Dallas) 1-wire bus instead of I2C for your application? 1-wire bus devices contain a unique 64-bit device identifier so you can attach more parts from the same manf. without identifier (address) conflict. The 1-wire master software's easy enough to implement, probably freely available, and can do device discovery at the start. That'd give you the Plug'n'Play you're trying to get.